# Feature Request: Is it fair to award reputation to users who contribute answers to questions?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I know Stack Exchange users have the privilege to contribute an answer to a question or a question once they join a Stack Exchange site (unless they are "banned" from doing so). But, I believe that reputation should be awarded for contributing answers to questions (maybe 2 or 3 reputation points). Is this fair (it will apply to all users) enough, and if it is, can we add it as a feature to all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: I'd like to pre-emptively explain that voting works different on meta, and upvotes or downvotes simply mean "agree" or "disagree", not that it's a "bad question" (lots of people are confused by this).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will only invite a flood of bad answers with people answering for the sake of answering and points. Having reputation *only* for upvotes means you actually have to put some effort in your answer (and even then we get plenty of answers of dubious quality).

So I'm sorry, but this is a terrible idea as it's abused far too easily. In an honest world with honest and flawless people it would be a good idea, though!

I can understand you want some points for spending time and participating a such, and it's unfortunate that sometimes good answers get 0 upvotes. The universe is an unfair place.

Answer (score 8):

My baloney has a first name, it's O-S-C-A-R
My baloney has a second name it's M-A-Y-E-R
Oh I love to eat it every day
And if you ask me, why, I'll say...
'Cause Oscar Meyer has a way with B-O-L-O-G-N-A.

+2

Comment: -1 Because I'll be hearing this in my head for the rest of the week now.

Comment: No wonder @Carpetsmoker said that it would invite a flood of bad answers!